# How can I switch the bytecode target level in IntelliJ using Maven 3 profiles

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using maven profiles to switch between two "setups" in Intelli J. How can I switch the bytecode target level? That is: I want to change the following setting in compiler.xml

```
<bytecodeTargetLevel>
  <module name="finmath-lib" target="1.6" />
</bytecodeTargetLevel>
```

Note: I tried to perform this via the following part in the respective Maven 3 profile

```
<profile>
    <id>java-8</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

but this does not work!

Note: The pom.xml etc. belongs to the finmath lib project, and if you are interested, it can be found at [www.finmath.net](http://finmath.net/java)

Answer (score 6):

I am using [IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) and it works with following config ...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: can't you just keep `<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>` and   `<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>`?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan Please be cautious when using the answer as it was written back in 2015 ... or improve it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you want to change it to 1.8.

I've tried to switch IntelliJ's compiler version between 1.7 and 1.6 or 1.5 using Maven profile **successfully**.

However when you want to change it to 1.8, the config will be ignored.

I don't know whether this is maven's problem or Intellj's. 
It seems that the JDK 1.8 is not well  supported now, which is understandable.

Comment: Thank you (for understanding my problem and providing a hint that I did not expect something strange...). I assume IntelliJ has a bug here. Not maven. My maven build work all fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the **Maven Projects** tool window in IntelliJ and select the profile you want to use from the list.

Comment: This is exactly the point: Selecting that profile WILL NOT change compiler.xml accordingly.

Comment: Did you enable _File > Settings > Maven > Importing > Import Maven projects automatically_?

Comment: No. I click "Import Changes" manually after switching the profile. If I enable that switch, then the profile is imported manually. However: The bytecodeTargetLevel is not updated! My question is how to update the bytecodeTargetLevel with a Maven profile. I do know that I have to activate and import the profile... Anyone here switching from JDK 6 to JDK 8 via a Maven profile?!

Answer (score -1):

In IntelliJ 13, `File > Project Structure`, set the `Project language level` to 8.0.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The IntelliJ (13) GUI shows a project language level 8.0, but compiler.xml has the above setting for the module and running the unit test fails. Of course: I can fix this by manually fixing compiler.xml (even deleting) - which is even faster than going to the GUI. Beside that: My question is how to switch the language level (of the module) using maven.